# how to use maxPoolSize with mongodb-php driver version 1.2.0

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

How to use `maxPoolSize` with mongodb-php driver version 1.2.0.

Does new mongodb php driver use connection pooling, if yes then how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Mongo::setPoolSize(1);
```

for this.

For explanation please refer :-

[MongoDb:setpoolsize](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.setpoolsize.php)

Comment: Thanks for help, but this option is available with legacy driver and for specific version. My question is for new mongodb-php driver.

Comment: In the documentation it is mentioned (PECL mongo >=1.2.0) on the top , so this should work for the new Mongo driver also